# how to get all the products that start with J in Linq? ps Simple

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to get my head into Linq to Objects  and for the life of me it escapes me...I want to get a list of all the products where the _name starts with J.

```
            Product prod;


            for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++ ) {
                prod = new Product();
                prod._Name = "J" + i.ToString();
                prod._Surname = "F" + i.ToString();


            }
```

Update

```
            Product prod;
            List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();


            for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++ ) {
                prod = new Product();
                prod._Name = "J" + i.ToString();
                prod._Surname = "F" + i.ToString();

                productList.Add(prod);
            }

            var query = productList.Where(p=> p._Name.StartsWith("J"));
```

Thanks Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you haven't given a collection of any kind in your code sample, but assuming you have a collection called `products` you want something like:

```
var query = products.Where(prod => prod._Name.StartsWith("J"));
```

That will give an `IEnumerable<Product>`. If you want a `List<Product>` just add a call to `ToList()` to the end:

```
var query = products.Where(prod => prod._Name.StartsWith("J"))
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of this error, juste move the `Product proc;` in your loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++ ) {
    Product prod = new Product();
    ...
```